# Ebean find Entities recursively

Tags: playframework, ebean

Is there any way to configure Ebean to find all Model classes recursively in whole project? The default configuration is:
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
but I don't really want to keep all my Entities in models package.

Comment: Why don't you want to do so ? You can create packages in your `models` package to separate things the way you want.

Comment: I want to implement Domain-driven design, so I need to create separate packages for each aggregate.